# Safe, Secure, Random Number using only Vyper smart contracts (NO CHAINLINK VRF)

Tags: python, randomness, vyper, gambling

For the purposes of my gaming project I am ditching chainlink VRF in order to obtain a random number because honestly... I hate everything about chainlink. Paying .1 link for a random number is absurd and the whole process is extremely complicated and slow.

So without using Chainlink, and keeping everything in Vyper. How can I generate a truly random and secure number? I have to believe that this is possible. My ideas for this are using msg.sender as a seed and putting it through 4 layers of hashing using unique hashing algo's that in reality are impossible to crack without using a quantum computer. Many people say that it is a bad thing to use any ethereum address as a seed to create a random number, because supposedly it is predictable, but I can't see anybody being able to do this.

Let me know your ideas, or if we can brainstorm a way to beat Chainlink VRF and avoid paying insane network fees for what should be a simple calculation.